# SPLIT SCROLL FEATURE IN WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to get Wordpress with a split scroll effect, but the ones I see online have screens that both move in opposite directions, dependant on each other, and I don't like that.

I want one screen to stay stationary, while the other screen scrolls down. As an example of what I'm looking for, see website at - www.solomonshiv.com
What do I have to get to get that effect?  Thanks much.
Anna